# Add path before asdf (particularly pipx, respectively ~/.local/bin)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2, asdf-vm

I'm using `asdf-vm` on my MacBook in an `oh-my-zsh` environment. It works pretty well, except for one thing.

I have a bunch of python based tools which I don't want to be managed by asdf. They are installed via `pipx` which provides its own virtual environments for the tools. One example is `powerline-status`.

I repeatedly get into trouble when `asdf` adds itself at the very beginning of the `PATH` variable. It stubbornly tries to manage everything and I keep getting errors that the tools I want to manage through `pipx` are not installed in the respective `asdf` environment. Of course I can install them, but it's an annoyance since I have quite a lot of `asdf` environments (repositories with `.tool-versions`).

The solution would simply be to add `~/.local/bin` (or other paths) at the beginning of the PATH variable, before `asdf`.

However, wherever I add the `~/.local/bin` to the path (`.zshprofile`, `.zshrc`...), `asdf` somehow always slips past and pushes itself to the very beginning of the PATH.

So where do I have to add my path to the environment variable in order for it to work as I desire?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this should be to do the following (assuming you installed asdf via Git):

```
# Source asdf (this is where asdf adds itself to your $PATH
. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"

# Manually change the path after sourcing asdf, as asdf shouldn't mess with your $PATH again
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

If this doesn't work let me know. Another solution to this would be to configure vim to fallback to system version for Python - https://asdf-vm.com/manage/versions.html#fallback-to-system-version